# Syslink in ListView

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

If I have a listview control in report mode, how could I stick a syslink control into one of the columns?
I want to have a link the user can click in one of the columns.

Comment: if you plan on having a lot of columns containing hyperlinks you might want to consider an owner drawn listview. You could even render the syslink control directly to the listviews device context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listview control doesn't support this itself.

You could create a real Syslink control that's a child of the listview. You would need to sub-class the listview and reposition the Syslink control whenever the list scrolls (watch for WM_HSCROLL / WM_VSCROLL messages) or when items are added or removed, or when it's sorted. You can use LVM_GETSUBITEMRECT to find out where to position it.

Alternatively, you could handle it yourself by using NM_CUSTOMDRAW to display the "link" in a different color, and handle NM_CLICK to catch when the user clicks on the link. This would be the simplest method in my opinion. Note that if you want a hand cursor to be displayed over the link you would still need to sub-class the list and handle WM_SETCURSOR yourself.